# Measuring typographical emphasis: the “lawler” and “lawler weight”

Tags: discussion, style, formatting

> RegDwighт said: @Robusto wow, that's formatting to the max. Bold *and* italics *and* monospaced *and* in quotes. John has outlawlered himself.[¹](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7221823#7221823)

It occurs to me that this is something we can measure.

1. I propose that a single character’s *lawler weight* (lw) be the standard unit of measure of the typographical emphasis applied to it (such as bold face, larger font, italics, quotation marks, and block quoting). If a character has no typographical emphasis, lw=0. If it is emphasized in one way, lw=1. If it is emphasized in two ways, lw=2, and so on.
2. I propose that the *lawler* (ll) be the standard unit of measure of the typographical emphasis applied to a text as a whole, and be calculated as the ratio of the total lawler weight of the characters to the total number of characters.

For example, consider the text of the two numbered paragraphs above. The italicized characters have lw=1; the others have lw=0. The overall typographical emphasis is around 0.04 (4%) lawler.

The overall typographical emphasis of the John Lawler answer[²](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93955/14073) referred to by RegDwighт above is about 0.6 (60%) lawler.

(It is possible for a text to have a lawler greater than 1. The overall typographical emphasis of a paragraph which is both bolded and italicized in its entirety would be 2 (200%) lawler.)

Comment: If one could up vote for a great sense of humor, plus ten here.

Comment: I think this has turned out to be a quantification of the sense of humor possessed by ELU regulars. ;-) I do get why two people would closevote "not constructive", but the two "off topic" closevotes mystify me. The proposal is plainly meta discussion about ELU.

Comment: @Kris One is certainly allowed to upvote for humor. This is not ELU, it's meta. "On Meta, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness."

Comment: I'm tempted to provide the 5th close vote just for the meta-humor of it.

Comment: I believe the scale should be logarithmic, where plain text has a raw value of _1_, etc., but the lawler weight is the log of the raw value.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Is that to avoid cases of lawler > 100%?

Comment: I don't like to think I'm humourless, but it seems to me this should have been put in a chat room.

Comment: LMAO (plus eleven more characters).

Comment: @JohnLawler That isn't funny.

Comment: @MετάEd, no, I just think that there's decreasing marginal shock value to each new typographical ornament, and a logarithmic model is one way to model this.

Comment: Like the [Nichter Scale](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/npislands.html). BTW, I've always typographed like this on the Web, as this piece from around 20 years ago in plain HTML shows. The reason I use so much typography is because I intend to write like I sound when I'm lecturing about grammar, which I used to do for a living. Since the facilities are available here, I use'em. Why not?

Comment: I've just noticed that this is "closed as off topic by" a buncha people. Which topic is it off, just for curiosity's sake? It's at least funnier than the usual run of meta "questions", whatever _topic_ it's _off_.